# Create a new column in dataframe after subtracting variables in two columns conditional on values in another column lagged

Tags: r, dataframe

I am coding in R. I am trying to create a new column in my dataframe that takes values in the "2021" column for each value in the "Grade" column and subtracts from it the values from the "2020" column where the 2020 "Grade" value equals the 2021 grade value minus 1. Check out my dataframe and text below for more clarity.

Here is what my data frame looks like:

| grade | 2020 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23489 | 12937 |
| 2 | 13499 | 13475 |
| 3 | 208983 | 49558 |
| 4 | 21334 | 12049 |
| 5 | 208380 | 19348 |
| 6 | 21097 | 12380 |
| 7 | 10034 | 19824 |
| 8 | 13213 | 19248 |
| 9 | 270065 | 12982 |
| 10 | 215887 | 19408 |
| 11 | 10679 | 12904 |
| 12 | 23453 | 12084 |
| K | 23045 | 12931 |

I would like to create a new column X where, for example, row 1 would be [n_2021 where grade=1] -[n_2020 where grade=K], the second row would be [n_2021 where grade=2]-[n_2020 where grade=1], third row would be [n_2021 where grade=3]-[n_2020 where grade=2], and so on and so forth.

It's important to note that Grade is currently a **factor variable** and the other two columns are **numeric**.

My new dataframe should look like this (except the elipses in column X would be filled in with the appropriate values:

| grade | 2020 | 2021 | X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23489 | 12937 | -10108 |
| 2 | 13499 | 13475 | -10014 |
| 3 | 208983 | 49558 | 36059 |
| 4 | 21334 | 12049 | ... |
| 5 | 208380 | 19348 | ... |
| 6 | 21097 | 12380 | ... |
| 7 | 10034 | 19824 | ... |
| 8 | 13213 | 19248 | ... |
| 9 | 270065 | 12982 | ... |
| 10 | 215887 | 19408 | ... |
| 11 | 10679 | 12904 | ... |
| 12 | 23453 | 12084 | ... |
| K | 23045 | 12931 | ... |

How can I do this? Do I need a loop or can I use a function in dplyr?

Thank you!

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you want a new column (`dplyr::mutate`) that is the result of one column, minus a `dplyr::lag` of the other column.

Comment: Oh wow, I've never heard of dplyr::lag before. But from my quick google search, it seems to be exactly what I need. However, I would say that it's important to note (as I mentioned in my post) that grade 1 corresponds to K (K is at the bottom of the list currently). So the lag would need to take that into account.

Comment: It will evaluate to `NA`, but you can change that behavior by setting the `default` argument of `dplyr::lag` to be equal to the value in the K-th row

Comment: Okay! Could you show me what the code for that would look like?

Answer (score 0):

## Using base R

Assuming your dataframe is sorted by the column *grade*, you can subtract the column *2021* by the column *2020* shifted by 1.

```
grades$Xbase <- grades$X2021 - grades$X2020[c(length(grades$X2020), 1:(length(grades$X2020)-1))]
head(grades)
#      grade  X2020 X2021   Xbase
#1     1  23489 12937  -10108
#2     2  13499 13475  -10014
#3     3 208983 49558   36059
#4     4  21334 12049 -196934
#5     5 208380 19348   -1986
#6     6  21097 12380 -196000
```

## Using dplyr

Again assuming the dataframe is sorted by the column *grade*, `dplyr::lag` can be used, as [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5908830) suggested it.

```
grades$Xdplyr <- grades$X2021 - dplyr::lag(grades$X2020, default = grades$X2020[length(grades$X2020)])
head(grades)
#  grade  X2020 X2021  Xdplyr
#1     1  23489 12937  -10108
#2     2  13499 13475  -10014
#3     3 208983 49558   36059
#4     4  21334 12049 -196934
#5     5 208380 19348   -1986
#6     6  21097 12380 -196000
```

---

**Raw data**

```
grades <- data.frame(read.table(text = "grade   2020    2021
1   23489   12937
2   13499   13475
3   208983  49558
4   21334   12049
5   208380  19348
6   21097   12380
7   10034   19824
8   13213   19248
9   270065  12982
10  215887  19408
11  10679   12904
12  23453   12084
K   23045   12931", header = T))
```